# Что находится в char массиве на пустых ячейках?

Tags: c, char

Я сделал функцию `ft_strrev`, в которую передаём char массив, а функция меняет значения этого массива через указатель.
Я не понимаю, чем заполнен массив из 255 символов. Я только понимаю, что на 0 месте "a", на 1 месте "b", на 2 месте "c", на 3 месте "\0", обозначающий нулевой символ. А что на других местах?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void    ft_putchar(char letter)
{
    char c;

    c = (char)letter;

    write(1, &c, 1);
}

int*    calc_length_char(char* str, int* length_str)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (str[i])
    {
        i++;
    }
    *length_str = i;
    return 0;
}

char*   fill_copy_str(char* str, char* copy_str, int* length_str)
{
    int j;

    j = 0;
    while (j < *length_str)
    {
        copy_str[j] = str[*length_str - j - 1];
        j++;
    }
    return 0;
}

char*   return_str(char* str, char* copy_str, int* length_str)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (i < *length_str)
    {
        str[i] = copy_str[i];
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}

char*   ft_strrev(char* str)
{
    int length_str;
    char copy_str[255];

    calc_length_char(str, &length_str);
    fill_copy_str(str, copy_str, &length_str);
    return_str(str, copy_str, &length_str);

    return 0;
}

int     main()
{

    char random_str[255] = "abc";

    ft_strrev(random_str);

    printf("%s", random_str);
}
```

Comment: Мусор. Но это совершенно неважно...

Comment: @Harry я не понимаю

Comment: У вас не проинициализированы остальные элементы, соответственно они и ссылаются на мусор

Comment: Мусор, потому что вы их никак не инициализируете. Неважно, потому что вся интересующая вас информация завершается нулевым символом (соглашение о строках С). Что за ее пределами - не имеет значения, вы с ней не работаете.

Comment: @Harry а вот для хакера очень важно. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Массивы в C по умолчанию [создаются неинициализированными](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninitialized_variable), то есть заполненными тем, что было раньше на том месте в памяти, где сейчас выделена память под массив.

В том числе потому в конце строк пишут нулевой символ, чтобы точно знать где заканчиваются данные и начинается мусор, остатки от прошлой работы программы.

Нужно отметить что чтение из таких неинициализированных массиовов может привести к неожиданных ошибкам, [которые очень сложно отладить](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B3). Программируя на C, вы должны быть готовы к таким ошибкам, а значит никогда не читать данные из неинициализированных массивов, кроме случая, конечно, когда вы рассчитываете найти там какую-то информацию, которая обычно вам недоступна, например, оставшуюся от выполнения ранних частей программы.

Впрочем, также нужно отметить что такая ситуация характерна для языков для системного программирования, которые отдают вам на откуп инициализацию чтобы сберечь ещё немного циклов процессора. Более высокоуровневые языки, такие как Java или Python, инициализируют все переменные, а значит там вы имеете меньше шансов встретить ошибки описанного выше типа.